# Prove time complexity

Tags: analysis

```
Let T (n) = 1, and let
T(n) = x^k T(n/x)+ Cn^k

where C and k are constants. Prove that

T (n) = O(n^k log(n))
```

I want to prove the time complexity using Induction and not sure where to start. Can someone please help me.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What is the definition of `x`? Also the very first line looks wrong. `T(n) = 1` without any condition on `n`?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is pretty straight forward:

Base case, `n = 1`.
`T(1) = 1` is a constant so it is `O(n^klog(n))`

Induction hypothesis:
`T(m) = O(m^k log(m))` for all `m < n`.

Induction step:

`T(n) = x^k T(n/x)+ Cn^k`
by IH we have that this is
`T(n) = x^k D(n/x)^k log n/x + Cn^k`  for some constant `D`
`T(n) = D x^k n^k /x^k (log n - log x) + C*n^k` , x^k now cancels out
`T(n) = D n^k log n - D n^k log x + C*n^k`
largest term here is D n^k log n, so in O-notation
`T(n) = O( n^k log n)`